# Behaviour of /dev/stdout in Cygwin

Tags: shell, cygwin

I have a script (executed with **zsh 5.8**; but this should not be relevant in this case) in a Cygwin environment, which takes as parameter the name of some output file and writes to this files via redirection in various places, like this:

```
outfile=$1
: >$outfile # Ensure that the file exists and is empty.
.... do some work
command_x >>$outfile
.... do more work
command_y >>$outfile
... and so on
```

I would like to modify the behviour of the script in that if no parameter is supplied, the output of the commands goes to standard output instead. I thought that it would be sufficient to modify the script in one line:

```
outfile=${1:-/dev/stdout}
```

But nothing is written to stdout. Investigating the case further, I found that instead a **regular file** named `stdout` had been created in the `/dev` directory. It seems that in the Cygwin environment, /dev/stdout does not represent the standard output of the process.

How would I achieve my goal under Cygwin?

**UPDATE**

As requested by @matzeri, here is a simple testcase:

```
echo x >/dev/stdout
```

Expected behaviour: Seeing *x* on stdout

Real behaviour: A regular file /dev/stdout has been created

Comment: Can you run `ls -l /dev/std*` and post result ?

Comment: please post a simple complete test case.

Comment: Perhaps this will point you in the right direction: `$ echo Hi >> /proc/1746/fd/2` where 1746 is the pid of the bash shell in a mintty window.

Comment: @matzeri : Done. Is it now clearer to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on a standard windows installation the /dev/std* are a symlink to the /proc/self/fd/*

```
ls -l /dev/std*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Marco Kein 15 Jun 19  2018 /dev/stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Marco Kein 15 Jun 19  2018 /dev/stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Marco Kein 15 Jun 19  2018 /dev/stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
```

if for any reason that is not anymore true they can be recreated
by `/etc/postinstall/bash.sh.done` script

```
$ grep self /etc/postinstall/bash.sh.done
/bin/test -h /dev/stdin  || ln -sf /proc/self/fd/0 /dev/stdin  || result=1
/bin/test -h /dev/stdout || ln -sf /proc/self/fd/1 /dev/stdout || result=1
/bin/test -h /dev/stderr || ln -sf /proc/self/fd/2 /dev/stderr || result=1
/bin/test -h /dev/fd     || ln -sf /proc/self/fd   /dev/fd     || result=1
```

In that condition the command

```
$ echo x > /dev/stdout
x
```

produces the expected output on both `Bash` and `Zsh`

Comment: This works indeed! I guess that bash.sh.done is _supposed_ to be automatically executed by the Cygwin setup. I just recently updated my setup64.exe to the most recent version before downloading new packages; perhaps there is a bug in it, with the effect that it wasn't executed.

Comment: More likely you did something that removed the links. Bash was not updated recently

Comment: I don't think the problem has to do with bash, but maybe with the Cygwin setup program. Sometimes after running setup, the permissions of some files in the /etc directory are wrong (missing read permission), and I have to fix this manually.  I basically do then a `chmod ug+rw /etc/{profile,vimrc,wgetrc,bash.bashrc,bash.bash_logout,nanorc,man_db.conf}`, but this does not change anything in /dev. Perhaps I will now get used to run the post-install script after updating Cygwin.